# Dotnetnuke popup login control with the modalpopupextender

Tags: authentication, popup, dotnetnuke, modalpopupextender, wizard

I'm trying to create a modal popup login control for dnn using the ModalPopupExtender in the AjaxToolkit. An issue that I'm running into is that when I click the "Login" button on the popup login form, if the login fails for some reason or if the user needs to update some information before moving on, the modal popup is cleared and the user is never notified that they need to change the information and the login cannot proceed.

Does the ModalPopupExtender provide the ability somehow, to mimic a wizard type of interface so that if my login failed then the next control would be rendered in the popup (e.g. "user must change password"). Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wizard control inside of the modalpopupextender.